# Minimongo doesn't support $ operator in projections yet

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this document:

```
...
    "username" : "torayeff",
    "profile" : {
        ...
        "friends" : [
            {
                "_id" : "aSD4wmMEsFnYLcvmP",
                "state" : "active"
            },
            {
                "_id" : "ShFTXxuQLAxWCh4cq",
                "state" : "active"
            },
            {
                "_id" : "EQjoKMNBey7WPGamC",
                "state" : "new-request"
            }
        ]
        ...
    }
...
```

This is query for getting only **"state"** attribute of given user:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId1, 'profile.friends._id': userId2}, 
                    {fields: {_id: 0, 'profile.friends.state.$':1} });
```

In meteor I am receiving this error:

```
Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'activateFriendship' Error: Minimongo doesn't support $ operator in projections yet...
```

How can I rewrite above query without having error in minimongo?

Answer (score -1):

Use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) for finding nested array, and [$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) in your projection, so query as below :

```
Meteor.users.findOne({
  "_id": userId1,
  "profile.friends": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "_id": userId2
    }
  }
}, {
  "profile.friends.state.$": 1
})
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do like

EDIT : if you just want to grab the values without keys, use this

```
Meteor.users.distinct('profile.friends.state', {_id: userId1, 'profile.friends._id': userId2});
```

For usual cases :

```
Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId1, 'profile.friends._id': userId2}).select({ _id: 0, 'profile.friends.state':1 }).exec()
```

`$` project operator not required

Comment: this will return ["state" : "active", "state" : "active", "state" : "new-request"] while I need only 1 element, that is why I am using .$

Comment: This answer misses the point: how to get only the *one whole* object in the array that matches the query.