# Is there a $ operator alternative in Meteor's Minimongo?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I'm trying to query for a specific element inside an array in a Meteor collection on the client side, but Minimongo doesn't support the $ operator. Is there an alternative to filter my query so it returns just the specific element in the array?

My collection is structured like this:

```
{
  "userID": "abc123",
  "array": [
    {
      "id": "foo",
      "propA": "x",
      "propB": "y"
    },
    {
      "id": "bar",
      "propA": "a",
      "propB": "b"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to write a query that returns just the object in the array with id "foo". In Mongo, that query would be this:

```
collection.find({
  "userID": "abc123",
  "array.id": "foo"
}, {
  "array.$": 1
});
```

However, Minimongo doesn't support the $ operator in projections so this throws an error. I've tried similarly structured queries using $elemMatch, and attempted the [solution described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968721/minimongo-doesnt-support-operator-in-projections-yet) but it doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Is there an alternative means of querying for the one element in this array with Minimongo?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) to extract the first matching object in an array. Give something like this a try:

```
// Find all documents matching the selector.
const docs = Collection.find({ userId: 'x', 'array.id': 'y' }).fetch();

// For each document, find the matching array element.
for (let doc of docs) {
  let obj = _.findWhere(doc.array, { id: 'y' });
  console.log(obj);
}
```

Comment: I actually used find().fetch() and it did exactly what I was looking for. If you edit the answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: @JoshVickerson Have a look at the proposed edits. I'm still unclear if you are searching for an element in a single or multiple documents.

Comment: I'm looking for an element inside a single document. In my use case, the userId is guaranteed to be unique, so the find should only ever match one document. I then need a single element from the array in that document.

Comment: Huh. I'm surprised then that the original solution didn't work: `_.findWhere(Collection.findOne({userId: 'x'}).array, {id: 'y'})`